# Masonry gallery not stacking correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I have looked up so many answers on StackOverflow, nothing seems to be helping. I have the following code, it seems to be stacking well without the masonry initialized (for the images on the current test), but fails with it. Reason I need masonry, is because the images won't always line up.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv28yvak/9/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='gallery'>
  <!-- Grid sizing element 33.33% -->
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

  <!-- Two 50% -->
  <div class='masonry-item gallery-item image-half'>
    <a data-fluidbox="true" href="http://placehold.it/450x250"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/450x250" alt="450x250" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class='masonry-item gallery-item image-half'>
    <a data-fluidbox="true" href="http://placehold.it/450x250"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/450x250" alt="450x250" /></a>
  </div>

  <!-- One 100% -->
  <div class='masonry-item gallery-item image-full'>
    <a data-fluidbox="true" href="http://placehold.it/900x400"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x400" alt="900x400" /></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Three 33.33% -->
  <div class='masonry-item gallery-item image-third'>
    <a data-fluidbox="true" href="http://placehold.it/300x500"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="300x500" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class='masonry-item gallery-item image-third'>
    <a data-fluidbox="true" href="http://placehold.it/300x500"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="300x500" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class='masonry-item gallery-item image-third'>
    <a data-fluidbox="true" href="http://placehold.it/300x500"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="300x500" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery .gallery-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 400px;
}

.grid-sizer { width: 33.33%; }
.gallery .gallery-item img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.gallery .image-full {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.gallery .image-half {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.gallery .image-third {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: green;
}
.grid-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $gallery = $(".gallery");
$gallery.imagesLoaded(function() {
  $gallery.masonry({
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
     itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
    });
});
```

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xf07rf7s/) help?

Comment: Thanks, it worked in that case, but as I add more items, it breaks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You built a layout of 3 columns of 33.33% by setting `.grid-sizer` to 33.33%.

It's mean the 50% wide column fit in two columns and let space of 1 column of 33.33% beside, which is not enough for a second 50% wide column.

You should use a smaller multiplicator for `.grid-size` as :

```
.grid-sizer {
  width: 16.667%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You Need This

```css
.gal {
 
 
 -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
   
 
 } 
 .gal img{ width: 100%; padding: 7px 0;}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  
  .gal {
 
 
 -webkit-column-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
   
 
 }
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">


<h1>Pure Css Responsive Masonry Gallery</h1>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<hr>

 <div class="gal">
 
 <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
 
  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
  
   <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
   
   <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
   
   
  
   <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
   
   <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
   
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
   
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt=""><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
     <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
   
      <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
   
      <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
    
 </div>
 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Karan for the answer, but I am looking for a solution that can be achieved using the Masonry plugin since it is compatible with some earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add jquery for your initialization method for masonry. In addition you need to delete your external image loading resource.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
```

https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgi/6m154y5z/

Comment: I've included jQuery using JSFiddle's method of include. Yours looks like it works because the JavaScript broke because of two jQuery inclusions, thus CSS handles the rendering of the grids. As for the external images, the `imagesLoaded` plugin handles the wait until all the images loaded part.

Comment: ok so your grid-sizer column width is messing up your grid. You are setting all column width's as 33% of the page and then try to set one column as half the page 50%. You need to use 33%, 66% or 100. You could also use 20, 40, 60, 80. I can update answer once you decide a correct width.